# Gain of entropy

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

Can we really interpretate third thermodynamic law as unconditional gain of entropy of closed system?

For example, when they [separate U 235](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcgKDSwINOA#t=119), they drive the mix on the pressure barrier, so heavier U 238 continues in stream unlike U 235, which goes in different way.
Isn´t entropy decreased here?

Comment: Uranium separation is not a closed system. It is, indeed, a very power hungry process.

Comment: Are you sure that you understand what is the 3rd law of thermodynamic? which is talking about the unattained ground state, at near 0 tmperature.

Comment: @CuriousOne Oh, yes, thank you, so is the correct formulation "Gain of entropy is not a spontaneous procces." or "For decrease the entropy we need energy."? Anyway, what about, for instance, atoms in sup: If they are quick and they bump into the margin (the plate), they ricochet back to the center, if they are not, they just stay near the margin - so the entropy of the sup decrease. How is it posible?

Comment: @CuriousOne And regarding to closed system, where the entropy gains during this procces? I think sup and uran are both part of the closed system - the universe.

Comment: In Callen: Thermodynamics and Introduction to Thermostatistics, (2ed) page 108 there is an example discussing the issue of entropy generation and the minimum amount of work needed to effect the isotope separation; a very interesting read.